# Prevent redraw after onTouch event on view

Tags: android, view, redraw, ontouch

I have a view in my android app that displays a graph.

The problem is, the graph redraws itself at the end of the onTouch event. There's not function call in the onTouch event handler that would explicitly do this. When I debug to the end of the handler the graph is yet to be redrawn, but as soon as I continue the thread, the view is redrawn.

How can I prevent this?

Thanks,
Carmen